# rails routes using the do part for iteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-routing

I have a very basic question, am looking at some rails code similar to following but not able to interpret it, what are the REST urls and corresponding actions inferred from this? Can someone please help understand as I did not find any examples of similar routes.

```
map.resources :myresources do |item|
    item.resources :v, :controller => 'my_controller' do |v|
      v.resource :abc
    end
end
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

This is actually the old routing style.
Now you can just write the code this way:

```
resources :myresources do
  resources :v, :controller => "my_controller" do
    resource :abc
  end
end
```

With this code you will get these routes:

```
     myresource_v_abc POST   /myresources/:myresource_id/v/:v_id/abc(.:format)      abcs#create
 new_myresource_v_abc GET    /myresources/:myresource_id/v/:v_id/abc/new(.:format)  abcs#new
edit_myresource_v_abc GET    /myresources/:myresource_id/v/:v_id/abc/edit(.:format) abcs#edit
                      GET    /myresources/:myresource_id/v/:v_id/abc(.:format)      abcs#show
                      PUT    /myresources/:myresource_id/v/:v_id/abc(.:format)      abcs#update
                      DELETE /myresources/:myresource_id/v/:v_id/abc(.:format)      abcs#destroy
   myresource_v_index GET    /myresources/:myresource_id/v(.:format)                my_controller#index
                      POST   /myresources/:myresource_id/v(.:format)                my_controller#create
     new_myresource_v GET    /myresources/:myresource_id/v/new(.:format)            my_controller#new
    edit_myresource_v GET    /myresources/:myresource_id/v/:id/edit(.:format)       my_controller#edit
         myresource_v GET    /myresources/:myresource_id/v/:id(.:format)            my_controller#show
                      PUT    /myresources/:myresource_id/v/:id(.:format)            my_controller#update
                      DELETE /myresources/:myresource_id/v/:id(.:format)            my_controller#destroy
          myresources GET    /myresources(.:format)                                 myresources#index
                      POST   /myresources(.:format)                                 myresources#create
       new_myresource GET    /myresources/new(.:format)                             myresources#new
      edit_myresource GET    /myresources/:id/edit(.:format)                        myresources#edit
           myresource GET    /myresources/:id(.:format)                             myresources#show
                      PUT    /myresources/:id(.:format)                             myresources#update
                      DELETE /myresources/:id(.:format)                             myresources#destroy
```